# Как извлечь значение input, созданный функцией?

Tags: javascript

Есть инпут $selectInput, который создается функцией:

```
function createBlock() {
  const $addBlock = document.createElement('div');
  const $selectContacts = document.createElement('select');
  const $phoneOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $additionalPhoneOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $emailOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $vkOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $twitterOption = document.createElement('option');
  const $selectInput = document.createElement('input');
  const $clearBtn = document.createElement('button');

  $addBlock.classList.add('add-contact__contacts');
  $selectContacts.classList.add('add-contact__select');
  $selectInput.classList.add('add-contact__input');
  $clearBtn.classList.add('add-contact__clear-input', 'btn-reset');

  $phoneOption.textContent = 'Телефон';
  $phoneOption.value = 'phone';
  $additionalPhoneOption.textContent = 'Доп. тел.';
  $additionalPhoneOption.value = 'additional-phone';
  $emailOption.textContent = 'Email';
  $emailOption.value = 'email';
  $vkOption.textContent = 'Vk';
  $vkOption.value = 'vk';
  $twitterOption.textContent = 'Twitter';
  $twitterOption.value = 'twitter';
  $selectInput.placeholder = 'Введите данные контакта';
  $selectInput.value = 'Введите данные контакта';

  $selectContacts.append($phoneOption, $additionalPhoneOption, $emailOption, $vkOption, $twitterOption);
  $addBlock.append($selectContacts, $selectInput, $clearBtn);

  $selectInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if ($selectInput.value.trim().length === 0) {
      $clearBtn.style.display = 'none'
      $selectInput.classList.remove('add-contact__input--active-clear');
    } else {
      $selectInput.classList.add('add-contact__input--active-clear');
      $clearBtn.style.display = 'inline-block'
    }
  })

  $clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $selectInput.value = '';
    $clearBtn.style.display = 'none'
    $selectInput.classList.remove('add-contact__input--active-clear');
  })

  $btnCancelContact.addEventListener('click', () => {
    $modal.style.display = 'none';
    $inputName.value = '';
    $inputSurname.value = '';
    $inputLastname.value = '';
    $selectInput.value = '';
    $addBlock.remove();
  })

  return $addBlock
}
```

Необходимо получить его значение для формы:

```
$form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  function getSelectInputValue() {
    let res = null;
    let nodes = createBlock().childNodes;
    res = nodes[1].value;

    return res
  }
  console.log(getSelectInputValue());

  const client = {
    id: getID(dataClients),
    name: $inputName.value.trim(),
    surname: $inputSurname.value.trim(),
    lastname: $inputLastname.value.trim(),
    createDate: new Date(),
    changesDate: new Date(),
    contacts: getSelectInputValue(),
  }

  $inputName.value = '';
  $inputSurname.value = '';
  $inputLastname.value = '';

  dataClients.push(client);

  renderClients();
})
```

Если присваивать value в ручную, то value отображается, но при отправки формы приходит пустое значение. Подскажите, как это сделать?